# Changing the colours on a WPF ScrollViewer's ScrollBar without templating the entire control

Tags: .net, wpf, styles, scrollviewer

I want to change the background colours on the ScrollBar of a ScrollViewer, but I really really don't want to re-template the entire ScrollViewer control along with all the associated logic of managing the ScrollBar.

Is there some way of only changing the colours of the ScrollBar without re-specifying everything for the entire control?

Comment: Will this help - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37366/Styling-A-ScrollViewer-Scrollbar-In-WPF

Comment: That involves changing the entire template, which I don't want to do.

Comment: @thecoop Have you found a working solution for this ?